# How can I move from one side of the slider bar to the other?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am webscraping https://www.rogers.com/web/totes/wireless/build-plan and as you click on the phone and go to the page that contains the different permutations of plans you can move the slider to select one that is best for you. Now I wish to scrape the data after I move the slider each time. However, when I use Selenium, the bar doesn't start on the left side and and it arbitrarly hops around between points on the slider. For some phones my code runs into an error after passing the first point on the slider. And other times certain points on the slider are missed all together or clicked twice.

I have tried different CSS. Selectors but some limit the bar length miss all the different plan types. I have attempted to print the webElement info to see if its selecting something twice but it seems to be different each time. Therefore its not going through the slider consistently or according to what I want

```
#collects all different points in slider
    planSlider = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.desSliderWrapper div')))
    print(len(planSlider))

    #runs through slider points
    for plan in planSlider:
        time.sleep(2)

        print(plan)

        plan.click()
```

I would like to be able to iterate through the points from the left side of the slider to the right side in order regardless if it has 3 points or 5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic to select the plan and then get the details.

```
plans = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-slider li")
for planNum in range(1,len(plans)+1):
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
    plan = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.card-slider li:nth-of-type("+str(planNum) + ")")
    plan.click()
    print(plan.text)
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[strong['plans from:']]").text)
```

**Here is the output:**

[image]

**Edited:**

Here is the script that will select the plan.

```
# get the plan selection span
planSelector = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all']")

# set the mouse position based on the number of plans
numberOfPlans = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[starts-with(@class,'sectionTable tabCount-')])[1]//div[starts-with(@class,'sectionCol')]"))

for selectPlan in range(1,5): #<== just looping to make sure it's working for all the plans (remove this and uncomment "selectPlan" variable in the below line)

    # specify the plan that you want to select
    # selectPlan = 4 #<======== change this number based on your interested plan number
    percentage = round((100/(numberOfPlans-1))*(selectPlan-1),4)
    print(percentage)
    #select plan
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}))",planSelector)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','left: " + str(percentage) + "%;')",planSelector)
    time.sleep(1)
    # now trigger the mouse move event which will tiger the change in the price
    # this will make sure js attached to the element in DOM will trigger
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}))",planSelector)
    # time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}))",planSelector)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}))",planSelector)
    time.sleep(1)
    selectedPlan = driver.find_element_by_class_name("selectedPlanRed").text
    print ("Selected Plan:-" + selectedPlan)
    time.sleep(3)
```

**Poor screenshot to accommodate the size limit:**

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question supputuri. If you can go into the phones pages, then select details for any particular phone, and finally select new customer you will be directed to a page with all the phone and plan details. In the bottom right you can see a slide bar that can change the plan type. Thats what my question pertains to, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, let me take a look.

Comment: Updated the answer with the solution, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Will provide the detailed explanation tomorrow.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. Slight error - I dont believe you intended to put -1 at the end of  'selectplan-1'

    percentage = round((100/(numberOfPlans-1))*(selectPlan-1),4)

Comment: `selectPlan-1` is intended, we need that for the calculation purpose where the plan button should be moved.

Comment: Suppose there are 4 plans, then the plan button will have 4 positions (0,33.3333,66.6667 and 100). In order to achieve %, we have to (100/(4positions-1))*(postionNumber-1).

Comment: Eg: If you want to select 2nd plan, then the calculation will be (100/(4Positions-1))*(selectedPlan2-1) i.e round((100/3)*1)='33.3333'

Comment: Did you got it?